# Rust issue with declaring TcpStream in a struct

Tags: sockets, rust, struct, option-type

I am new to rust and have worked my way through the try it examples. I wanted to try and program a socket library. One issue i am running into early on is how to initialize a struct which has a TcpStream

```
struct connection{
    address: String,
    sock:    TcpStream,
}
```

when i started i didnt know how to initialize that type of object

```
impl connection{
   fn new(add: &str)->connection{
       connection{
             address: add.to_string(),
             //i didnt know what to put here
             // sock: TcpStream::connect(add.to_string()); ??this seems wrong.
       }
   }
}
```

i found an only question on here which says make TcpStream and Option

```
struct connection{
   address: String,
   sock: Option<TcpStream>,
}
```

this made the code very awkward as i could never just do sock::connect etc as sock was always within Some()

am i missing something? is there a way to do this where i can just declare it and be able to use it from the struct like all other variables without this Option thing?

if having it in an option is the only way to do it, is there a easy way to get it out of the option, the struct variable im using to reference it is always going to be an Option so i dont know how i can just access it normally without escaping Some()

Comment: Not sure what advice you're following that said to use `Option`, you'd do that if you for some reason going to initialize the stream later, which doesn't sound like what you want. You call using `TcpStream::connect` looks like the way to go, just you need to handle the result properly since attempting to connect can fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate struct initialization and TCP setup you can also create an unconnected `Socket` with the [socket2 library](https://docs.rs/socket2/latest/socket2/struct.Socket.html), convert that into a `TcpStream` and then later connect it by borrowing it as a `Socket`